# Nginx as a Load balance while login to application its saying invalid user id/password

Tags: linux, nginx, load-balancer

I  have configured nginx successfully. When I made a load balance with my two application servers (spring boot), when my application opens with the load balance IP, the application asks for a userid and a password. If I give the correct answer, then it's also showing me "incorrect id/password".

I have configured nginx on my spring boot application and I am able to login with the same user id/password.

Can you suggest me where I am going wrong in my configuration?

**My config file is as follows:**

```
upstream backend {    
  #server 10.26.2.50:80;
  server 10.10.2.76:80;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name  _;

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;    
  proxy_pass http://backend;

  location /private/public/ {
    auth_basic off;
  }
}
```